# Codigniter routes

Tags: codigniter

Почему не работает данный маршрут?

```
$route['admin/category/(:any)/products'] = 'admin/products/$1';
```

Comment: `$route['admin/category/([^\/]+)/products'] = 'admin/products/$1';` ?

Comment: тоже не работает

Comment: Если убираю в роуте admin то работает,подскажите почему

Comment: видимо по умолчанию роутинг в codigniter работает так: то что идет до первого слеша - это класс к которому следует обратиться, то что идет между первым и вторым слешами - это метод который надо вызвать, дальше - параметры для вызываемого метода.

Comment: Самое интересно что 2 почти идентичных роута,один работает второй нет

Comment: $route['admin/add_product/(:num)'] = 'admin/edit_product/$1';
$route['admin/edit_product/(:num)'] = 'admin/edit_product/$1';